# if (aCHAR == 'character' || 'another character') problems

Tags: c++, char, boolean

Hi so i'm trying to check a certain character in a string to make sure it's not a \,=,|, etc. and replacing the space with the "player" character if it's not but the function is returning true everytime, even if char newLoc is equal to '' (empty):

screen.get_contents returns a vector container full of strins, and
sprite.get_location returns an int array with two number, [0] representing X, [1] is Y.

```
bool check_collision(Sprite& sprite,int X, int Y, Screen& screen) 
    {
    ////////////////////// check whats already there /////
        char newLoc = screen.get_contents(sprite.get_location()[0]+Y,sprite.get_location()[1]+X);
        if (newLoc == '|' || '/' || '_' || '=' || 'X' || 'x' )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };
```

what is the problem? **Thanks!!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need:

```
if (newLoc == '|' || newLoc == '/' || ...)
```

What you have written is equivalent to:

```
if (newLoc == ('|' || '/' || ...))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (newLoc == 1)
```

Note that a cleaner way of writing this might be:

```
switch (newLoc)
{
case '|':
case '/':
...
    return true;

default:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but why does the IDE come up with 1??

Comment: @Griffin: `||` is the *logical OR operator*.  If either of its arguments is `TRUE`, then it "returns" `TRUE`.  A character literal evaluates to `TRUE` unless it is the null character `'\0'`.  So the RHS of the expression equates to `TRUE`.  This in turn evaluates to `1` when interpreted as an integer value.

Answer (score 4):

```
newLoc == '|' || '/' || '_' || '=' || 'X' || 'x'
```

doesn't work, you must do it like this:

```
newloc == '|' || newloc == '/' || etc...
```

However this is more easy to read:

```
switch (newloc):
    case '|':
    case '/':
    case '_':
    case '=':
    case 'X':
    case 'x':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
```